# get nearest key,value based on variable in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, sorting, key-value

I have a data like

```
ask = 
{'C-BTC-23500-020123': {'best_ask': '5.2'},
'C-BTC-23550-020123': {'best_ask': '5.1'},
'C-BTC-21000-030123': {'best_ask': '5.22'},
'C-BTC-21200-030123': {'best_ask': '5.23'},
'C-BTC-23000-060123': {'best_ask': '5.25'},
'C-BTC-24000-060123': {'best_ask': '5.26'},
'C-BTC-23100-130123': {'best_ask': '5.27'},
'C-BTC-23150-130123': {'best_ask': '5.28'},
'C-BTC-22000-200123': {'best_ask': '5.205'},
'C-BTC-24000-090223': {'best_ask': '5.256'},
'C-BTC-14500-270123': {'best_ask': '228.66'}}
```

I have spot price and list of dates as

```
spot_price=23031
dates=['020123', '030123', '060123', '130123', '200123', '270123', '240223']
```

for each dates i need nearest key,value of ask variable with referance to spot price.

Example:

for date 020123
spot = 23031

so the values for the date are

```
'C-BTC-23500-020123': {'best_ask': '5.2'},
'C-BTC-23550-020123': {'best_ask': '5.1'},
```

the nearest key,value based on the strike is

`C-BTC-23500-020123: {'best_ask': '5.2'}`

Tried with round method, but differant expiry has differant round numbers so its not working.

Comment: You should separate the commodity name from the date -- two separate columns.

Comment: how do i do that.

Comment: Could you help me in the following to rearrange and get desired output

Comment: Need the nearest value for the date with referance to spot price.

Comment: The way your question is formulated implies the reverse: looking up the date first then finding the nearest price. You should edit your question to make it clearer, post your exisiting code, and provide expected output and actual output.

Comment: @Swifty Rearragned the question

Comment: That doesn't explain 'Tried with round method, but differant expiry has differant round numbers so its not working.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the key-value pairs of your dictionary and extract the price with `split('-')`:

```
ask = {
    'C-BTC-23500-020123': {'best_ask': '5.2'},
    'C-BTC-23550-020123': {'best_ask': '5.1'},
    'C-BTC-21000-030123': {'best_ask': '5.22'},
    'C-BTC-21200-030123': {'best_ask': '5.23'},
    'C-BTC-23000-060123': {'best_ask': '5.25'},
    'C-BTC-24000-060123': {'best_ask': '5.26'},
    'C-BTC-23100-130123': {'best_ask': '5.27'},
    'C-BTC-23150-130123': {'best_ask': '5.28'},
    'C-BTC-22000-200123': {'best_ask': '5.205'},
    'C-BTC-24000-090223': {'best_ask': '5.256'},
    'C-BTC-14500-270123': {'best_ask': '228.66'}
}

def find_spot_for_date(data: dict, date: str, spot: int) -> dict:
    diff = spot
    res = None
    for k, v in data.items():
        if date in k:
            price = int(k.split('-')[2])
            if abs(price - spot) < diff:
                diff = abs(price - spot)
                res = {k: v}
    return res

print(find_spot_for_date(ask, "020123", 23031))
```

Output:

```
{'C-BTC-23500-020123': {'best_ask': '5.2'}}
```

Comment: With minor changes here in recursive function, its working fine. Thank you for taking time and sorting my issue.